# Why the cost of the clustered index in databases differs?

Tags: database, b-tree

[image: cost of cluster index]

The cost of the clustered index adds up an additional 2 * pages * D and there is an additional +4 in Insert/Delete.

How do these additional terms show up?

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wo1s65uEfuQ&list=PLYp4IGUhNFmw8USiYMJvCUjZe79fvyYge&index=60) of CS186 at U of California Berkeley has been confusing me.

Comment: This should be asked on DBA Stackexchange, and you'd need to add tags that indicate which database you are talking about.

Comment: Please use text, not images/links/videos, for what can be given as text. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Especially don't ask us to watch video.

Comment: You need to clearly give your reasoning with justification per competent references or there is nothing to critique.